# Swift Converting Optional String to Int

Tags: json, swift, http-headers, alamofire

this seems like a pretty basic question but for some reason haven't been able to get it resolved.  I'm using Alamofire to parse JSON and trying to get a header value that tells me my current api rate limit.

```
if let xRate = String(describing: response.response?.allHeaderFields["X-Ratelimit-Remaining"])as String? {
    self.jsonCallsRemaining = xRate                    
    print("json: ", xRate)
    print("json2: ", Int(xRate))                    
}
```

When trying to get the Int of xRate (or Float, or Double) I get 'nil'.  In the consolve i'm seeing:

json:  Optional(79)

json2:  nil

It appears that the number is coming back as an optional string.  Am I missing something obvious?  New to Swift.  Thanks!

Comment: Get rid of the `as String?` at the end of the `if let` line.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy but Int(xRate) is still coming back as nil.

Comment: @user2452063 Then perhaps the string isn't a valid decimal integer.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I had thought that originally but couldn't get it as a Float or Double either. When printing out the string it does show the number  like: (89).

Comment: is it in brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, your `String.init(describing:)` is extraneous and unnecessary.

```
    if let xRate = response.response?.allHeaderFields["X-Ratelimit-Remaining"] as? String {
        self.jsonCallsRemaining = xRate
        print("json: ", xRate)
        print("json2: ", Int(xRate))
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  I could have sworn that I tried this when troubleshooting, thanks!